# PHP date_create isn't displaying the right hour

Tags: php, time, format, unix-timestamp

I have a Unix timestamp which i want to convert to a regular time(String).
My Unix timestamp:

```
1385767232382
```

My script:

```
$date = date_create(date('c', "1385767232"), new DateTimeZone('PST'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i');
```

I removed the last three digits from the Unix timestamp becuase i got a really strange time, so then i changed it from miliseconds to seconds by removeing the last three digits.

The date returned by the script:

```
2013-11-29 23:20
```

The date it should return:

```
2013-11-29 15:20
```

I tried a few other dates and they are all the same. Only the hours aren't good, the rest is fine.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: 03:20 -> 15:20

Comment: whats is the timezone ur trying and what was the timezone for the unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone is not correct because the second argument of `date_create` is ignored when the first argument specifies a timezone (see note in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-parameters)). In your case the format used *does* specify a timezone, and because `date` does not accept one explicitly that timezone is the default system timezone instead of PST.

This is the correct way to do it:

```
$d = date_create('@1385767232');
date_timezone_set($d, new DateTimeZone('PST'));

echo $d->format('Y m d H:i:s');  // 2013 11 29 15:20:32
```

Comment: Just to know, whats the use of @ sign here ? @1385767232

Comment: @mazraara: It's just a way to tell `date_create` that you are passing in a timestamp. See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime(1385767232382));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
echo(date("Y-m-d H:i", "1385767232"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why your doing the extra works like removing 3 digi..?

The actual the below gives correct one..
$date = date_create(date('c', "1385767232"), new DateTimeZone('PST'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i');

you are getting trouble may be analyzing timeZone, make sure with that.